# Why this strategy is true...

Tags: prime-numbers, distribution-of-primes

To find prime number if we want to be sure, why can't we just put odd number of zeros between two ones and get a prime number, and also why this becomes true and how to prove it.

Example:
101
10001
1000001

Comment: This is false.  $10001=10^4+1=73\times 137$.

Comment: You are true I have post this by mistake

Comment: And $1000001=10^6+1=101\times 9901$.

Comment: "I have post[ed] this by mistake."  You can self-delete your Question until you are able to edit it properly, at least so long as it has no answer posted.

Comment: If $10^n+1$ is prime, then $n$ must be a power of $2.$ The converse is unlikely to be true, but I don’t have an example.

Comment: A prime of the form $10^n+1$ with $n>2$ must have millions of digits, if such a prime exists at all. In general, we cannot guarantee to find a new prime if we insert digits , to find huge primes is a difficult task.